# django many to many query for existence

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many

Here is my django model

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    quiztype = models.ForeignKey(QuizType)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Quiz #1{0}".format(self.id)


class Translation(models.Model):
    left_word = models.ForeignKey(Word, related_name='trans_left_word')
    right_word = models.ForeignKey(Word, related_name='trans_right_word')
    quizes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return u"{0} => {1}".format(self.left_word.word_text, self.right_word.word_text)
```

I am trying to find all of the translation objects that are not apart of the quiz object. I suppose I could slice query sets from the two but that seems like a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isnull` check to get that.

```
Translation.objects.filter(quizes__isnull=True)
```

this will give you all translations which are not connected to any quizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```
Translation.objects.exclude(quizes= Quiz.objects.all())
```